# Run VirtualBox in Docker to achieve running Genymotion in Docker

Tags: docker, virtualbox, genymotion

I'm trying to install Genymotion into a Docker, but I'm having problems with VirtualBox. This is my DockerFile:

```
FROM     ubuntu:15.04
MAINTAINER paulo.ch8

RUN apt-get update &&  \
    apt-get install -y wget && \
#                       qtwebkit && \
    echo 'deb http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian trusty contrib' >> /etc/apt/sources.list && \
    wget http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian/oracle_vbox.asc -O /tmp/oracle_vbox.asc -q && \
    apt-key add /tmp/oracle_vbox.asc && \
    apt-get update &&  \
    apt-get install -y virtualbox-4.3 && \
    apt-get clean

RUN apt-get update &&  \
    apt-get install -y bzip2

RUN apt-get install -y libgstreamer0.10-dev libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-dev
RUN apt-get install -y linux-headers-3.19.0-22-generic
# RUN apt-get install -y lspci
RUN /etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup

# Install GenyMotion
ADD genymotion-2.5.2_x64.bin /tmp/genymotion.bin


RUN echo 'y' | /tmp/genymotion.bin -d /genymotion/

# RUN /usr/sbin/useradd --create-home --home-dir /home/nonroot --shell /bin/bash nonroot && \
#     /usr/sbin/adduser nonroot sudo
# USER nonroot
# WORKDIR /home/nonroot
```

I have my genymotion.bin installer with chmod +x in my Dockerfile folder so it can be ADD and executed.

I ran the build with the command:

```
docker run -ti --rm --net=host
             -v $HOME/.Xauthority:/root/.Xauthority
            -e DISPLAY=unix$DISPLAY
            -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix
            --privileged
            --name=genymotion-test
             genymotion:teste16  /bin/bash
```

After, I ran the command which I've found at docker.hub jess/virtualbox :

```
docker cp virtualbox:/etc/init.d/vboxdrv .
docker cp virtualbox:/usr/src/vboxhost-4.3.28 /usr/src/ 
docker cp virtualbox:/usr/share/virtualbox /usr/share
./vboxdrv setup
```

But I'm having the following problem:

[image]

When I try to run a created virtual machine I have this error:

[image]

Comment: maybe you should add to your run command `-v /dev/vboxdrv:/dev/vboxdrv`like I see it at https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/esben/vboxinsidedocker/ Anyway I think you either need to copy a file (like you copied some using `docker cp`  or mount it in the `docker run` command

Comment: hello Paulo we are working on the same and curious to know if you were able to get this working?

Comment: Hello @VenuMurthy. I didn't find any way to run VirtualBox into docker... If you find tell me please!

Comment: Hi there, have you managed to sort this out? I have a running docker container running ubuntu 12.04 x64, inside the container I have my android studio setup and also virtual box and genymotion, both run as expected. Let me know if you are having issues and I can send you my Dockerfile

Comment: Hello @Francois, I would like to see your Dockerfile if it's possible, we are planning to do the same ;)

Comment: I also has similar issues with running vbox inside container, apparently the container uses the host machine's kernel, to keep the docker container as light as possible.

Comment: So my solution was to rather install vbox/geny on the host and share the correct dirs and ports with the docker container for debug ect purposes

Comment: You can find my Dockerfile here --> https://bitbucket.org/fmarais/docker-android-studio-marais/src

Comment: ## Start new container, 1st time (no container), Genymotion
xhost + && \
sudo docker run -it \
-e DISPLAY \
-v /dev/bus/usb:/dev/bus/usb \
-v $HOME/projects/android:/home/developer/projects \
-v $HOME/programs/genymotion:/home/developer/genymotion \
-v $HOME/.Genymobile:$HOME/.Genymobile \
--net=host \
-p 8600-8699:8600-8699 \
--name android-studio \
android-studio/marais \
/home/developer/android-studio/bin/studio.sh

## Start existing container, 2nd time
xhost + && sudo docker start android-studio

Answer (score 0):

I also has similar issues with running vbox inside container, apparently the container uses the host machine's kernel, to keep the docker container as light as possible. (This is using a linux host)

So my solution was to rather install vbox/geny on the host and share the correct dirs and ports with the docker container for debug ect purposes

The important step is to expose the genymotion ports and directories to the container.

## My current setup

Host

- Ubuntu 15.04
- VirtualBox 4.3.34
- Genymotion 2.6.0
- Android project files

Docker container

- Ubuntu 12.04
- Java 8
- Android Studio 2.0 Preview

## Start new container, 1st time (no container), Genymotion

```
xhost + && \
sudo docker run -it \
-e DISPLAY \
-v /dev/bus/usb:/dev/bus/usb \
-v $HOME/projects/android:/home/developer/projects \
-v $HOME/programs/genymotion:/home/developer/genymotion \
-v $HOME/.Genymobile:$HOME/.Genymobile \
--net=host \
-p 8600-8699:8600-8699 \
--name android-studio \
android-studio/marais \
/home/developer/android-studio/bin/studio.sh
```

## Dockerfile source

https://bitbucket.org/fmarais/docker-android-studio-marais/src

```
# NOTE
# Items marked with ## are comments
# items marked with # are code snippets that can be enabled

FROM ubuntu:12.04
MAINTAINER Francois Marais <fm.marais@gmail.com>




##  --------------------- Before you build
##  1. (MANDATORY) Download the android studio zip 
##  https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html#Other
##  copy the zip to to the Dockerfile directory and rename to 
##  'android-studio.zip'

##  2. (MANDATORY) Download Java JDK tar.gz 
##  http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html
##  copy the java jdk tar.gz to the Dockerfile directory and rename to 
##  'jdk.tar.gz'

##  3. (OPTIONAL, ENABLE IF YOU WANT TO USE EXISTING SDK DIR) 
##  copy your android sdk directory to the Dockerfile directory and rename to 
##  'android-studio-sdk' 
RUN mkdir -p /home/developer/android-studio-sdk
COPY android-studio-sdk /home/developer/android-studio-sdk

## 4. (OPTIONAL, FOR GENYMOTION) 
## Install virtualbox and genymotion on the host machine
## Install geymotion under $HOME/programs/genymotion on the host machine
## Use the genymotion start method





## --------------------- Build and Run
##  Check that you have your 
##  1. android-studio.zip 
##  2. jdk.tar.gz
##  3. optional android-studio-sdk folder
##  Build with the following command
#docker build -t android-studio/marais .

##  Start new container, 1st time (no container), not using Genymotion
#xhost + && \
#sudo docker run -it \
#-e DISPLAY \
#-v /dev/bus/usb:/dev/bus/usb \
#-v $HOME/projects/android:/home/developer/projects \
#--net=host \
#--name android-studio \
#android-studio/marais \
#/home/developer/android-studio/bin/studio.sh

##  Start new container, 1st time (no container), Genymotion
#xhost + && \
#sudo docker run -it \
#-e DISPLAY \
#-v /dev/bus/usb:/dev/bus/usb \
#-v $HOME/projects/android:/home/developer/projects \
#-v $HOME/programs/genymotion:/home/developer/genymotion \
#-v $HOME/.Genymobile:$HOME/.Genymobile \
#--net=host \
#-p 8600-8699:8600-8699 \
#--name android-studio \
#android-studio/marais \
#/home/developer/android-studio/bin/studio.sh

## Start existing container, 2nd time
#xhost + && sudo docker start android-studio




## --------------------- Init and tools
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y \
nano \
unzip \
bzip2 \
git \
libxtst6 \
libxtst6:i386 \
lib32stdc++6 \
libxrender-dev \
libxi6 \
libgconf-2-4

## Git flow
RUN apt-get install -y \
git-flow




## Required for android studio gradle build process
RUN apt-get install -y \
libncurses5:i386 \
libstdc++6:i386 \
zlib1g:i386

## Bash-it for git shell
RUN git clone --depth=1 https://github.com/Bash-it/bash-it.git ~/.bash_it && \
~/.bash_it/install.sh




## --------------------- Java Installation (/usr/lib/jvm/java-oracle-jdk)
## Download you desired java JDK, http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html
RUN mkdir -p /usr/lib/jvm/java-oracle-jdk
COPY jdk.tar.gz /tmp/jdk.tar.gz
RUN tar zxf /tmp/jdk.tar.gz -C /usr/lib/jvm/java-oracle-jdk --strip-components=1
RUN rm /tmp/jdk.tar.gz
ENV JAVA_HOME /usr/lib/jvm/java-oracle-jdk

## --------------------- Android studio installation (/home/developer/android-studio)
## Download android studio, https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html#Other
## Project files from host machine in $HOME/projects/android
RUN mkdir -p /home/developer/projects

COPY android-studio.zip /tmp/android-studio.zip
RUN unzip -d /home/developer /tmp/android-studio.zip
RUN rm /tmp/android-studio.zip

## Set up USB device debugging
RUN mkdir -p /etc/udev/rules.d
COPY 51-android.rules /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules
RUN chmod a+r /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules

## Add env for studio
ENV PATH $PATH:/home/developer/android-studio-sdk/tools
ENV PATH $PATH:/home/developer/android-studio-sdk/platform-tools
```